# Unexpected token export in typescript package

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I am including a module (from a private git repo)

Package.json:

```
"my-module": "git+https://username:pw@bitbucket.org/username/repo.git"
```

The repo has a typescript file:

```
export class MyClass {}
```

This module is intended to be used on both a node & browser environment.

When I run it in my node environment I get an error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export class MyClass {}
```

The module I am including doesn't have a dist folder (I.E it isn't precompiled).

What is going wrong here? Do I need to precompile it and reference the dist folder or is there a way to access the src directly?

Both the imported module & importing project have a tsconfig.json with `target: "es6", module: "commonjs"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typescript project recommends that you don't compile dependencies, but rather build them before publishing packages.

This is hard in your case because you're using a git dependency. In that case I would suggest to either:

1. Compile your dependency and store the built files in git.
2. Change your `tsconfig.json` to also compile files from that dependency directory.